# TypeScript: tryParseInt with a default value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement a very simple helper method that accepts two arguments: the first one is of type any or null, the second is either number or null. The results of the method should be:
`{success: true, value: number}`, `{success: false, value: null}` if a default value is null or `{success: false, value: number}` if default value is a number.

My target is to get a compilation error, when parsing was not successful and a default value was not specified:

```
const result = tryParseInt('blah');
const num1: number = result.success === true ? result.value : result.value;
```

I'm almost done with the implementation but got stuck with the conditional types. Double expressions are not allowed and I can't find a good alternative for `R = T extends true ? number : DT extends number ? number : null`

Error says:

```
Type 'DV' is not assignable to type 'number | (DV extends number ? number : null)'.
  Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number | (DV extends number ? number : null)'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | (DV extends number ? number : null)'.(2322)
```

My code ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqVEAUCGUDOwAkgHYwDqAljABYAiwAZjgK4A2MASsPuzADwAoOOjigYwEgBN8cAEYQIbYDhIAaYXDpiQE6bJIsAtnOBQ4AHzgtpTSiWBSNIznAC8o8ZJkIoLVAD8cIYmZnAAXFqaAHzucADevADGSTz4kWhqcABuOGz%20kZwAvgDcgoKgkLBwjDZJMJQQJL7YeISkAmg6ej4hpuZWNlJ2DlLRABS5%20cCRqoiWwexsWcPMfABqef4BGQCUmhmYuATEZFS0DGsc3Lwc-DB%20wFlosVYYrScd5-RMrNc8fH4zDYhGesXi5RElEYcEmW1Qbg8hjYbF2CU0IigwBgLCgzUSLBSaUiwNBOXhkVWfxgm2mpU0RUhcGhsMo%20AAcjh2XDprs0RCRJjsbj8clUvh0jU8mSpgU4FSNvD6SJGZoWeMkCgIDDZQjEXAAOR9MwG-kYuBYnF4hJi4m%20fxZXWRXXKuCqkRJJr4eBgNqOWn%20OK%20z5kHkOuAARgADLsymqYeM2ZzucHCFIA8A%20ejBRbhdaCUSJSTpU9ydNKb9FXSyiqmZaRTbCeLJQ9w064Kn-UqykUgA)):

```
type TryParseIntResult<
  T extends boolean,
  DT extends number | null,
  R = T extends true ? number : DT extends number ? number : null
  > = {success: T, value: R};

function tryParseInt<DV extends number | null>(value: any | null, defaultValue: DV)
  : TryParseIntResult<true, DV> | TryParseIntResult<false, DV> {

  if (value == null) {
    return {success: false, value: defaultValue};
  }

  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return {success: true, value: value};
  }

  const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);

  if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    return {success: false, value: defaultValue};
  }

  return {success: true, value: parsedValue};
}
```

BTW, if you know about a NPM package that contains helpers with similar functionality, that would be even better!

**UPDATE:**
As suggested below, I tried 'zod'. Unfortunately current version of this package doesn't fulfill my expectations. Here is the code with my comments "current behavior vs expected behavior":

```
const numberSchemaWithDefault = z.number().default(12);
    const intSchemaWithDefault = z.number().int().default(22);

    const intParseResult1 = numberSchemaWithDefault.safeParse("blah");
    const intParseResult2 = intSchemaWithDefault.safeParse("blah");

    console.log(intParseResult1.success); // => false, no default value => expected 'fallback' (or something like this) with default value
    console.log(intParseResult2.success); // => false, no default value => expected 'fallback' (or something like this) with default value

    if (intParseResult1.success) {
      console.log(intParseResult1.data); // never logged
    }

    if (intParseResult2.success) {
      console.log(intParseResult2.data); // never logged
    }

    const intParseResult3 = numberSchemaWithDefault.parse("blah"); // => error => expected 12
    const intParseResult4 = intSchemaWithDefault.parse("blah"); // => error => expected 22

    console.log(intParseResult3);
    console.log(intParseResult4);
```

Comment: I think that all your statements can be collapsed in `return {success: !isNaN(parseInt(value)), value: isNaN(parseInt(value)) ? parseInt(value) : defaultValue}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @astef and the source code from "zod" project I was able to finish my helper method (unfortunately just with a nullable fallback value, optional argument doesn't work).

Basically, the solution was to split my super-generic `TryParseIntResult` type (where `success` is boolean) into two sub-types with a `success` property explicitly typed to `true` or `false`.

Here is the final version:

```
export type SafeParseSuccess = { success: true; value: number };
export type SafeParseError<DV> = { success: false; value: DV };

export type SafeParseReturnType<DV> =
  | SafeParseSuccess
  | SafeParseError<DV>;

function tryParseInt<DV extends number | null>(value: any | null, defaultValue: DV)
  : SafeParseReturnType<DV> {

  if (value == null) {
    return {success: false, value: defaultValue};
  }

  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return {success: true, value: value};
  }

  const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);

  if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    return {success: false, value: defaultValue};
  }

  return {success: true, value: parsedValue};
}
```

If someone forgets to provide a fallback value like in this example:

```
const t = tryParseInt('blah', null);
const r: number = t.value;
```

then a compilation error occurs:

```
Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm not directly answering your question, but I was in the same situation, trying to parse things by myself, and I wish somebody would just show me this way of doing this.

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

```
import { z } from "zod";

const intSchema = z.number().int();

const intParseResult = intSchema.safeParse("blah");

if (intParseResult.success) {
  console.log(`Success: ${intParseResult.data}`);
} else {
  console.log(`Error: ${intParseResult.error}`);
}
```

Output:

```
Error: [
    {
      "code": "invalid_type",
      "expected": "number",
      "received": "string",
      "path": [],
      "message": "Expected number, received string"
    }
  ]
```

Actually, that's a very tiny bit of what you can parse and validate, check it out by yourself.

If not this library, here are the competitors, doing pretty much the same thing:

https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts

https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes

https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/superstruct

Comment: This kind of helpers I was able to find. "zod" is great but my target was to have a fallback value, which by some reason authors decided not to implement in `safeParse` method. Anyway, thx to your answer I was able to make my implementation working :)

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy are you sure https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#default is not what you are looking for?

Comment: default doesn't work as expected for strings. Try, for example, z.number().default(12).parse('w12')